# Can I make ctrl + right/left go to the next/last capital letter rather than the next/last word respectively, in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I often use these shortcuts in Eclipse, and the shortcut will bring you to the next capital letter in the word- for example:

```
variableName|
```

pressing ctrl + left arrow will make the cursor go like this:

```
variable|Name
```

However, this is not how it works in Visual Studio. It goes to the next word, rather than the next capital letter. I don't know how to search for this problem on Google.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017.

Comment: The eclipse behavior is non standard. Most editors use ctrl+left/right as moving to the next word instead of moving to the next boundary in camel case

Comment: It's imperative that I use Visual Studio. Using a different editor is not an option.